# InkWell not showing ripple effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, ripple-effect

Tapping the container triggers the `onTap()` handler but does not show any ink splash effect.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: (){print("tapped");},
          child: new Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried putting the `InkWell` inside the `Container` as well but in vain.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

I think adding color to the container is covering over the ink effect

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell/InkWell.html

This code seems to work

```
  body: new Center(
    child: new Container(
      child: new Material(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: (){print("tapped");},
          child: new Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
          ),
        ),
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ),
```

just click the middle square.

Edit: I found the bug report. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3782

> This is actually as expected, though we should update the docs to make it clearer.
>
> What's going on is that the Material spec says that the splashes are actually ink on the Material. So when we splash, what we do is we literally have the Material widget do the splash. If you have something on top of the Material, we splash under it, and you can't see it.
>
> I have wanted to add a "MaterialImage" widget that conceptually prints its image into the Material as well so that then the splashes would be over the image. We could have a MaterialDecoration which does something similar for a Decoration. Or we could have Material itself take a decoration. Right now it takes a color, but we could extend that to taking a whole decoration. It's not clear whether it's really material-spec-compatible to have a material with a gradient, though, so I'm not sure whether we should do that.
>
> In the short run, if you just need a workaround, you can put a Material on top of the container, with the material set to use the "transparency" type, and then put the ink well inside that.

--hixie

Update: Hixie merged a new Ink solution last year. The Ink provides a convenient way to splash over images.

```
  testWidgets('Does the Ink widget render anything', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      new Material(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Ink(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            child: new InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.green,
              onTap: () { },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


Material(
  color: Colors.grey[800],
  child: Center(
    child: Ink.image(
      image: AssetImage('cat.jpeg'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: 300.0,
      height: 200.0,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () { /* ... */ },
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text('KITTEN', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Please Note: I did not test the new Ink Widget. I coped the code from ink_paint_test.dart and the Ink class docs

https://github.com/Hixie/flutter/blob/1f6531984984f52328e66c0cd500a8d517964564/packages/flutter/test/material/ink_paint_test.dart

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13900

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html

Comment: You can just put the color on the `Material` itself and leave out the `Container`.

Comment: I kinda figured when CopsOnRoad posted his answer.

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Try CopsOnRoad answer. I did not edit my solution because CopsOnRoad's solution is pretty elegant

Comment: That is what I used after some refactoring :D thanks

Comment: in my case it was the Container shape, thanks fo the solution

Answer (score 231):

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

Use **`Ink`** widget wrapped in an **`InkWell`**.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {}, // Handle your onTap 
  child: Ink(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
)
```

Comment: The source confirms step 3: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/79b5e5bc8af7d9df3374dfe6141653848d1c03ac/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L504 In each handler they check if the callback is available, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad, may I ask you to have a flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539378/flutter-cannot-use-flexible-inside-padding-for-text-wrapping-purpose ?

Comment: If by the full code you mean the example you've given then yes. I've found this to be the solution > https://stackoverflow.com/a/58556613/12140067

Comment: @Chris I think you might be having some `Theme`' or `Material`'s interference, because this code works all day long.

Answer (score 74):

1. The InkWell widget must have a Material widget as an ancestor otherwise it can't show effects. E.g.:

   ```
   Material(
     child : InkWell(
       child : .....
   ```
2. you have to add `onTap` method to see the actual effects as like

   ```
    Buttons {RaisedButton,FlatButton etc}.
    e.g -> Material(
                child : InkWell(
                        onTap : (){}
                        child : .....
   ```

Let's come to the main points see some examples below and try to understand 
      the actual concepts of InkWell.

- In Below example Material is parent of InkWell with onTap but it still not working. Please try to understand the concept of it. You should provide some margin to container or other widget to show the effects. Actually below code working fine but we can't see because we did not provide any margin or align so it has no space to show the effects.

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print("tapped");
          },
          child: new Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),  
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- Below example show InkWell effects only to upwards because we provide space {margin}.

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print("tapped");
          },
          child: new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- Below exp. show the effects in all the page because center create margin from all the side. Centre align it's child widget from top, left, right and bottom.

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print("tapped");
          },
          child: Center(
            child: new Container(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't realise that it must have `Material` Widget as parent, and adding that instantly solved  the issue!

Answer (score 39):

InkWell() will never show the ripple effect until you add the

```
onTap : () {}
```

or any of the callbacks like onDoubleTap, onLongPress etc.

parameter inside the InkWell as it starts listening to your taps only when you specify this parameter.

Comment: Yeah I did, and its true. Check the source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/79b5e5bc8af7d9df3374dfe6141653848d1c03ac/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L504 In each handler they check if the callback is available, otherwise nothing happens.

Answer (score 23):

I have found this solution for me. I think it can help you:

```dart
Material(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    )
```

`Color` is given to Material widget. It is the default color of your widget.
You can adjust color of ripple effect using `splashColor` property of Inkwell.

Comment: Yes. It works. If you happen to use a `Container`, then replace it with `Material` and make it the parent of the `InkWell` and then style your `Material` Widget with color/padding/etc.

Answer (score 17):

2023 update :
very simple you have to have

Container -> Material -> InkWell in this order.

```
              Container(
                    width: 114,
                    height: 64,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColorsLight.surfacePrimary,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                    ),
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: 
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
```

Answer (score 15):

A better way is to use the [`Ink`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Ink-class.html) widget instead of any other widget.

Instead of defining `color` inside container you can define it in `Ink` widget itself.

Below code will work.

```
Ink(
  color: Colors.orange,
  child: InkWell(
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    ),
    onTap: () {},
  ),
)
```

> Do not forget to add a `onTap: () {}` in the `InkWell` else it will
>   not show the ripple effect too.

Answer (score 12):

If you want a **Ripple** **Effect** on any widget just:

1- Wrap widget with **Material** and **Inkwell**.

2- set color to widget from **Material**.

3- **Never** set **color** to the widget you want it to ripple.

```
   Material (
   color: const Color(0xcffFF8906),
   child: InkWell(
   ontap:() { },
   child: Container(
   color: Colors.transparent,
   height: 80,
   width: 80,
 )
```

Answer (score 7):

Quick solution in easy words:

This solution works in any place of the widget tree.
Just add additional Material before InkWell, like so:

```
return Container(
  .......code.......
  ),
  child: Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        .......code.......
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Reference:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html
Section called "The ink splashes aren't visible!"

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the `InkWell` with `Material` and use there the color that you need:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: (){ print("tapped"); },
            child: new Container(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way I found and use it always. You can try it.

- Wrap your `Widget` with `InkWell`
- Wrap `InkWell` with `Material`
- Set the opacity 0% anyhow. e.g.: `color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),`

  ```
  Material(
    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
    child: InkWell(
      child: Container(width: 100, height: 100),
      onTap: (){print("Wow! Ripple");},
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: pro tip --> you can also use the Colors.transparent

Comment: not working for me so i use this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697978/9372923

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```
Material(
    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.orange,
      child: Text('Hello'), // actually here it's a Container wrapping an image
      onTap: () {
        print('Click');
      },
    ));
```

After trying many answers here, it was a combination of:

1. Setting `splashColor`
2. Wrapping `InkWell` in `Material(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0), ..)`

Thanks to the answers here that make those 2 points

Answer (score 3):

```
child: Material(
color: Colors.transparent
child: InkWell(
  onTap: (){ print("this Ripple!";},
  splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
  child: Container(
    height:100.0,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
),
```

Add `Material` before `InkWell` and set `color` to `Colors.transparent`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of providing the color for the `Container` widget, provide color for the `Material` widget.

```dart
Material(
      color: Colors.orange,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("tapped");
        },
        child:  Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem trying to create an alternating color of InkWell's in a ListView.  In that particular case, there's a simple solution: wrap the alternates in a Container that uses a mostly transparent tint/brightness change -- the InkWell touch animation will still be visible beneath it.  No Material needed.  Note there are other issues when trying to work around this with a Materal -- e.g., it will override a DefaultTextStyle you're using with the default (it installs an AnimatedDefaultTextStyle) which is a huge pain.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make my situation work by using a Stack.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    MyCustomWidget(), //              <--- Put this on bottom
    Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Ink(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

The reason that the other answers on this page weren't working for me is that my custom widget hid the ink effect and I didn't have a plain image (so I couldn't use Ink.image).

#### Edit:

You still may be able to use `Ink.image` if you [convert the image to the right format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773283/3681880).

Answer (score 2):

#### Single Line:

Use **`splashColor`** widget in an **`InkWell`**.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {}, // Handle your onTap 
  splashColor: Colors.grey,
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have set the properties in theme or parent of the material

```
ThemeData(
 ...
 splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
 ...
)
```

if you don't want splash effect for specific use it explicitly

```
 InkWell(
          splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
          ...
          child: Row(
          ...
          )
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you have not added the below properties in the material theme:**

(In my case this was the issue)

```
splashColor: Colors.transparent
splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory
```

eg:-

```
MaterialApp(
  home:......,
  theme: ThemeData(
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory, // Remove this
    splashColor: AppColors.transparent, // Remove this OR Change the color
    ......         
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you added `onTap:(){}` listener, ripple effect should work fine. It doesn't work if you use `BoxShadow()` with in the `InkWell()` widget.

Comment: That's the trick. Ripple will not work without onTap(). Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

now using MaterialButton, in newer version flutter

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        child: Text(
          labelText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        color: backgroundColor,
        height: 45,
        minWidth: double.infinity,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For handling ripple effect you should use the below rules:

1. `onTap` shouldn't be `null` (or empty).
2. InkWell must be inside any of the Material Widgets

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom widget if any of the previous solutions are not working for you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BaseInkWell extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function()? onTap;
  const BaseInkWell({Key? key, required this.child, this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        child,
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: onTap,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

to use it

```
BaseInkWell(
 child: Container(),
 onTap:()=>print('works')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing an issue where the ripple animation is not visible when using InkWell within a BottomSheet in my Flutter app. I've tried various solutions, but the ink effects seem to be going behind the card.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
    void showDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        height: 200.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: SelectBox(),
      );
    },
  );
}

class SelectBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue,
      onTap: () {
        print("Tapped");
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Label 1'),
            const Text('Label 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After trying different approaches, the solution that worked was to place the Ink widget as the root in the BottomSheet. Here's the updated code:

```
    void showDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Ink(
        height: 200.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Other widgets can be added here
            SelectBox(),
            // Additional widgets
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}

class SelectBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue,
      onTap: () {
        print("Tapped");
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Label 1'),
            const Text('Label 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This adjustment ensures that the ink effects are rendered correctly on top of other content within the BottomSheet. Please let me know if you have any insights or suggestions on how to improve this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by a similar problem adding an Inkwell to an existing complex Widget with a Container wrapping a BoxDecoration with a color. By adding the Material and Inkwell in the way suggested the Inkwell was still obscured by the BoxDecoration so I just made the BoxDecoration's color slightly opaque which allowed the Inkwell to be seen

Answer (score 0):

The solution to circular widgets, do like below:

```
Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              enableFeedback: true,
              iconSize: 40,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.skip_previous,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 40,
              ),
              onPressed: () {}),
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 100,
            enableFeedback: true,
            splashColor: Colors.grey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled, color: Colors.white, size: 100),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
              enableFeedback: true,
              iconSize: 40,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.skip_next,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 40,
              ),
              onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was another problem. InkWell was not showing ripple effect when i had onTap function as parameter of my widget defined as below.

```
Function(Result) onTapItem;
...
onTap: onTapItem(result),
```

I don't know what's the difference, but next code is working well.

```
onTap: (){ onTapItem(result); },
```

Comment: Methods are executed when built. You need an enclosure to save a function

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52407983/1462442

Answer (score 0):

Adding transparent color to Material worked in my case:

```
  child: new Material(
    color: Colors.transparent
    child: new InkWell(
      onTap: (){},
      child: new Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create a widget that **supports tap**.
> 2. Wrap it in an InkWell widget to manage tap callbacks and ripple
>    animations.

that's point 2 mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/gestures/ripples)

example:

```
InkWell(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Tapped'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by just using Card Widget on the top of InkWell Widget like this:

```
Card(               elevation: 0,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white54,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      onTap:(){},
                      child: Container(
                        width: size.width * 0.5,
                        height: 230,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
```