# InkWell ripple over top of image in GridTile in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use `InkWell` to get a ripple effect on top of an image inside of a `GridTile` when the user taps on the tile.

I believe the image itself is obscuring the ripple because when I remove the image, I see the ripple.

Below is the code for a single GridTile.

```
return new InkWell(
  onTap: () => debugPrint(s.displayName),
  highlightColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
  splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
  child: new GridTile(
    footer: new GridTileBar(
      title: new Text(s.displayName),
      subtitle: new Text(s.gameName),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
      trailing: new Icon(
        Icons.launch,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    child: new Image.network( //this is obscuring the InkWell ripple
      s.imageSrc,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
   ),
 );
```

I've tried moving the InkWell to different levels of the hierarchy, using `DecorationImage` inside a `Container`, but none of these seem to work to reveal the ripple.

How can I get the ripple to appear on top of the tile/image?

Comment: Thant's pretty strange that Image has a higher elevation than InkWell indeed, despite the hierarchy

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I was able to get a ripple to appear over the image by using a [Stack](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#using-material-design) and wrapping the InkWell in a [Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect) widget.

```
return new Stack(children: <Widget>[
        new Positioned.fill(
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: new GridTile(
              footer: new GridTileBar(
                title: new Text(s.displayName),
                subtitle: new Text(s.gameName),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
                trailing: new Icon(
                  Icons.launch,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              child: new Image.network(s.imageSrc, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        ),
        new Positioned.fill(
            child: new Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: new InkWell(
                  splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  onTap: () => _launchStream(s.displayName),
                ))),
      ]);
```

Comment: I have transparent inkwell , using it inside material also makes it opaque to background image

Answer (score 73):

I think this would be a better way to show ripple effect over image.

```
Ink.image(
    image: AssetImage('sample.jpg'),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
    ),
),
```

The root cause is that Flutter renders views in descending order. when we put our image as the child of InkWell, the effect is covered by that image.

Find out more references here:

[The Ink widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13900)

[Create a Rounded Image Icon with Ripple Effect in Flutter](https://medium.com/@RayLiVerified/create-a-rounded-image-icon-with-ripple-effect-in-flutter-eb0f4a720b90)

Comment: This solution doesnt allow to create rounded corners for the image

Comment: I considered this approach, but I believe there is no way to get this to work with a more complex widget (e.g. Container which contains text and image)?

Answer (score 71):

Using [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) we can bring `Material` and `InkWell` over the image. To stretch Material we are going to use [`Positioned.fill`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned/Positioned.fill.html) widget.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image( ... ),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () { ... },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/ed0fd320a28f1f27999dff67ee5f2302) | [Gist](https://gist.github.com/TheMisir/ed0fd320a28f1f27999dff67ee5f2302)

### Screenshot

This screenshot is taken from given dartpad link.

[image: InkWell ripple over the Image]

Comment: Tried all suggestions here. This one works the best for me since I have `AspectRatio` and `FadeInImage` for the main layer.

Comment: @TheMisir this is the only soultion which worked with cachednetwork image Loved it!

Comment: Pretty nice, works well with FadeInImage present inside a card also

Comment: Set `InkWell` splashColor to `Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)` to get better ripple animation

Answer (score 17):

We have created this simple Widget to paint an ink reaction on top of any given child.

```
class InkWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color splashColor;
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  InkWrapper({
    this.splashColor,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        child,
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: splashColor,
              onTap: onTap,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Lost formatting of the child widget. Fixed using `Positioned.fill(child: child)`

Answer (score 13):

Screenshot:

[image]

```
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: Ink(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: ExactAssetImage("chocolate_image"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      splashColor: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.5),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Excellent approach. Works even with `AspectRatio`. What would be even better if I could use `FadeInImage`.

Answer (score -4):

wrap `InkWell` inside `Material` Widget

```
Material(   
  child : InkWell(          
      child : YourWidget     
  )      
)
```