# Flutter: How do you make a card clickable?

Tags: material-design, flutter

I just have a simple Card like `new Card(child: new Text('My cool card'))` and I want to be able to click anywhere on it to run some function, except there's no `onPressed` method for a Card. I could add a button to the bottom, but that's not ideal for this situation.

Anyone know how to make the whole card clickable?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping in a `GestureDetector`?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Flutter use composition over properties.
Wrap the desired widget into a clickable one to achieve what you need.

Some clickable widgets : [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), [`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html), [`InkResponse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html).

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => ......,
  child: Card(...),
);
```

Comment: How effective it is when there is List of gesture detector i am mostly interested in its usage in listview

Comment: That's the same stuff.

Comment: @RémiRousselet This works fine. But it doesn't show any ripple effect. I tried wrapping it in `InkWell` even that failed to show ripple effect. Seems like we need to do bit more nesting like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Well that's not the topic of this question

Comment: @RémiRousselet Absolutely right. But I thought maybe there is something tiny (some property) I was missing and your comment could have helped. But anyways, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad To have ripple effect you may want to wrap the `child` of `Card` inside of a `InkWell`. The ripple effect can't be displayed in your case because it will be behind the `Card`.

Answer (score 81):

Flutter provides the [InkWell](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples) Widget. by registering a callback you can decide what happens when user clicks on the card (called tap in flutter). [InkWell](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples) also implements Material Design ripple effect

```
Card(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      print("tapped");
    },
    child: Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: It seems to me that the Inkwell should probably be *outside* the Card

Comment: @forresthopkinsa: that depends on what you want to achieve. If you want the Card to fill with the "ink", then the InkWell should be inside the Card. Instead, if the InkWell wraps the Card, then an area (by default, a rectangle) outside of the card (but not inside the Card) will fill with the "ink." You can even have an Inkwell each inside and outside the Card - whereby both areas fill with "ink."

Comment: I think the question was to make the entire card clickable and not the container of 100x100 inside a card

Comment: @nonbeing sure, that makes sense

Comment: If the card has a non-transparent background (`color` argument) and you want that colour to change on hover/tap, then the InkWell needs to be inside the Card.

Comment: If your card is not rectangular the ripple effect will go outside the border of the card. To address that make sure you add a `clipBehavior` to your `Card`. like `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge`

Answer (score 36):

I think you can also use [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) apart from [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) just wrap the card inside `InkWell()` Widget

```
InkWell(
  onTap: (){ print("Card Clicked"); }
  child: new Card(),
);
```

Comment: I had to place the InkWell into the Card widget in order to get the ripple effect

Comment: Card ( child: InkWell() ) is better

Answer (score 17):

You can use Inkwell and insert splashColor which, at the click of the user, creates the rebound effect with the chosen color, on the card ..
This is mainly used in material design.

```
return Card(
  color: item.completed ? Colors.white70 : Colors.white,
  elevation: 8,
  child: InkWell(
      splashColor: "Insert color when user tap on card",
      onTap: () async {

      },
    ),
);
```

Comment: Could you explain how is your answer different than others recommending `InkWell`?

Comment: I simply entered this answer because in the others there was no splashColor which, at the click of the user, creates the rebound effect with the chosen color, on the card ..
This is mainly used in material design

Comment: @AlexPad, answer is on point. And given the rapid transition of onTap(), a highlight color might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 9):

Wrap a card in GestureDetector Widget like a below:

```
 GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      // To do
    },
    child: Card(
     
    ),
  ),
```

Another way is as follows:

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      // To do
    },
    child: Card(),
  ),
```

Answer (score 7):

In Flutter, InkWell is a material widget that responds to touch action.

```
InkWell(
    child: Card(......),
    onTap: () { 
        print("Click event on Container"); 
    },
);
```

GestureDetector is a widget that detects the gestures.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { 
        print("Click event on Container"); 
    },
    child: Card(.......),
)
```

**Difference**

InkWell is a material widget and it can show you a Ripple Effect whenever a touch was received.

GestureDetector is more general-purpose, not only for touch but also for other gestures.

Answer (score 2):

The most preferred way is to add `ListTile` as `Card` child. Not only does `ListTile` contain the method `onTap` it also helps you in making Card interesting.

```
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text('Title')
    leading: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/test.jpg'),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      print('Card Clicked');
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: What does ListTile enable that I can't do with Card alone (apart from gesture detection)?

Comment: @Ian nothing, besides conformity with material patterns when making a list of cards. While that is common, Card can certainly be used outside of a list.

Answer (score 1):

You also can insert a card into a TextButton:

```
TextButton clickableCard = TextButton(child: card, onPressed: onCardClick, style: [...]);
```

This brings the advantage, that you get some features for free. For example in Flutter Web, you get a mousover effect and the cursor changes to the hand so that ths user knows, he can click there. Other additional features can be customised using the style.

Answer (score 1):

Do something on tap/click of 'child' in Flutter:-

Code:-your code looks like:

```
child: Card(------
------------
--------),
```

**Step1**:- Put your mouse cursor on `Card` then, press- `Alt+Enter`(in windows) `select wrap with widget`.

**Step2**:- Change your default widget into `GestureDetector`.

final code:-

```
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: YourOnClickCode(),
child: Card(------
------------
--------),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers are brilliant but I just want to share mine for the one who wants to make/show a ripple effect on Tap of card or list tile.

```
Card(
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: ()=> ...,
    child: ListTile(
           title: Text('title'),
  ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better UX while clicking the `Card`, I suggest you add `InkWell` as the `Card`'s child. This gives the true Material 3 effect when clicking the `Card`. The code snippet below would do just that:

```
return Card(
  child: InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    onTap: () {},
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'This is a Clickable Card!',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        Text('Try This Out!'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

As long as `onTap` is not null (having (){} is enough to make it not null), you will end up with the desired splash effect, AND you'll have a clickable `Card`. Also, the current `Card` widget in Flutter 3.7.10 comes with `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)`. Therefore, it is necessary to add the same property to `InkWell` for a better UX.