# Create a rounded button / button with border-radius in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm currently developing an Android app in Flutter. How can I add a rounded button?

Comment: This here have mentioned multiple ways https://mightytechno.com/rounded-button-flutter/

Answer (score 1033, accepted):

**1. Solution Summary**

`FlatButton` and `RaisedButton` are deprecated.

So, you can use `shape` which placed in the `style` property, for `TextButton` and `ElevatedButton`.

There are some changes since Flutter 2.0:

- `style`: the property type has changed to [`ButtonStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html)
- `shape`: the property type has changed to [`MaterialStateProperty<T>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html)

**2. Rounded Button**

Inside the `style` property exists the `shape` property:

```dart
style: ButtonStyle(
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
    RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

**Square Button**

For a square button you can use `ElevatedButton` or otherwise add:

```dart
style: ButtonStyle(
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
    RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

**Complete Example**

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    TextButton(
      child: Text(
        "Add to cart".toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)
      ),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(15)),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
          )
        )
      ),
      onPressed: () => null
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(
        "Buy now".toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)
      ),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
          )
        )
      ),
      onPressed: () => null
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: This code works, but can't we remove the `shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(...)` portion and just directly assign a `RoundedRectangleBorder(...)` to the `shape` property?

Comment: @fpsColton Sure, in fact I can't even have it to work via `MaterialStateProperty`, only using `RoundedRectangleBorder(...)`. I am getting error otherwise, which looks like this: `The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty<RoundedRectangleBorder>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'OutlinedBorder?'.`

Answer (score 445):

### Update

Since the left-sided buttons are now deprecated, use the right-sided ones.

```
Deprecated    -->   Recommended

RaisedButton  -->   ElevatedButton
OutlineButton -->   OutlinedButton
FlatButton    -->   TextButton
```

---

- #### `ElevatedButton`

1. Using **`StadiumBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: StadiumBorder()),
   )
   ```
2. Using **`RoundedRectangleBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), // <-- Radius
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```
3. Using **`CircleBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: CircleBorder(),
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
     ),
   )
   ```
4. Using **`BeveledRectangleBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```

---

#### `OutlinedButton`

1. Using **`StadiumBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   OutlinedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: StadiumBorder(),
     ),
   )
   ```
2. Using **`RoundedRectangleBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   OutlinedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```
3. Using `CircleBorder`:

   [image]

   ```dart
   OutlinedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: CircleBorder(),
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
     ),
   )
   ```
4. Using **`BeveledRectangleBorder`**

   [image]

   ```dart
   OutlinedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text('Button'),
     style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
       shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```

---

#### TextButton

`TextButton` also works similar to `ElevatedButton` and `OutlinedButton`, however, you can only see the shapes when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 292):

You can use the `ElevatedButton` Widget. The elevated button widget has a `shape` property which you can use as shown in the below snippet.

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.teal, 
                      width: 2.0,
                  ),
              ),
          ),
      ),
      child: Text('Submit'),
      onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: RaisedButton is deprecated and no longer used. Use Elevated button with ButtonStyle as suggested by Peter

Answer (score 75):

**Since September 2020, Flutter 1.22.0:**

> Both "RaisedButton" and "FlatButton" are deprecated.

#### The most up-to-date solution is to use new buttons:

#### 1. `ElevatedButton`:

[image: Button without an icon]

[image: Button with an icon]

Code:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("ElevatedButton"),
  onPressed: () => print("it's pressed"),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red,
    onPrimary: Colors.white,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Don't forget, there's also an `.icon` constructor to add an icon easily:

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
  label: Text("Like"),
  onPressed: () => print("it's pressed"),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

#### 2. `OutlinedButton`:

[image: Outlined button]

Code:

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.star_outline),
  label: Text("OutlinedButton"),
  onPressed: () => print("it's pressed"),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    side: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.blue),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

#### 3. `TextButton`:

You can always use `TextButton` if you don't want an outline or color fill.

Answer (score 45):

You can simply use [RaisedButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html)

---

```dart
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 150.0, right: 0.0),
  child: RaisedButton(
    textColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.black,
    child: Text("Search"),
    onPressed: () {},
    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Output:

[image]

More info: [RSCoder](http://www.rscoder.com/2019/12/create-rounded-buttonbutton-with-border.html)

Comment: 'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.

Answer (score 41):

You can simply use [`RaisedButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html) or you can use [`InkWell`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) to get a custom button and also properties like `onDoubleTap`, `onLongPress`, [etc.](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html):

```
new InkWell(
  onTap: () => print('hello'),
  child: new Container(
    //width: 100.0,
    height: 50.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      border: new Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    child: new Center(child: new Text('Click Me', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),),),
  ),
),
```

[image]

If you want to use the `splashColor` and `highlightColor` properties in the `InkWell` widget, use the [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html) widget as the parent of the `InkWell` widget instead of decorating the container (deleting the decoration property). [Read about why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect).

Comment: If you want the `InkWell` to clip to the rounded corners then you need to add `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)` to the `InkWell` widget also otherwise it will go to the edges of the bounding rectangle.

Comment: @VictorRendina I was searching for a way to make the ripples rounded, thanks for ur comment. add this as a sperate answer to inkwell questions as many aren't mentioning this.

Answer (score 21):

Different ways to create a *rounded* button are as follows:

**ElevatedButton with ElevatedButton.styleFrom**

```
ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
          child:
              Text("Buy now".toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
        ),
```

**ElevatedButton with ButtonStyle**

```
ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
          ))),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Submit".toUpperCase()),
        ),
```

A practical demonstration of a round button can be found in the below Dartpad link:

#### [Rounded Button Demo Examples on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/10b1ea01e8f615555e50b126362408dc?)

[image: Screenshot of dartpad]

Answer (score 16):

In the new update `flutter 3.0` flutter uses `Material 3` guidelines

According to which the ***default border of buttons are rounded***

**`Default Button`**

```
  ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Default Button ")),
```

[image]

**`Button with Border Radius Zero`**

```
 ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero)),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("Border Radius Zero ")),
```

[image]

**`Button with custom border radius`**

```
  ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50))),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("Border Radius Custom ")),
```

[image]

Note: You can use the same logic for `FilledButton`, `TextButton` and the like.

Refer https://m3.material.io/components/all-buttons for button style.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the below code to make a rounded button with a gradient color.

```
 Container(
          width: 130.0,
          height: 43.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              // Where the linear gradient begins and ends
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              // Add one stop for each color. Stops should increase from 0 to 1
              stops: [0.1, 0.9],
              colors: [
                // Colors are easy thanks to Flutter's Colors class.
                Color(0xff1d83ab),
                Color(0xff0cbab8),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Sign In',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontFamily: 'Righteous',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            onPressed: () {

            },
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 10):

[image: How it looks!]

Use [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) instead.

Buttons like the FlatButton, RaisedButton and OutlineButton has been said to be deprecated since October 2020. This is one of the Flutter development team's effort to simplify and make the Flutter API consistent, you can customize its style by using style property.

```
      TextButton(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: Text('Text here',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
        ),
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.teal,
          onSurface: Colors.yellow,
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 2),
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Pressed');
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 8):

To use any shape in your *button*, make sure you perform all the code inside the *Button* widget:

```
 **shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red) ),**
```

If you want make it is *square*, use `BorderRadius.circular(0.0)` It automatically makes it into a *square*.

The button is like this:

[image]

Here is the all source code for the give UI screen:

```
 Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF8E44AD),
    body: new Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 10, 20, 0),
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 92.0),
            child: Text(
              "Currency Converter",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 48,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                labelText: "Amount",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                labelText: "From",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  labelText: "To",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          MaterialButton(
            height: 58,
            minWidth: 340,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "CONVERT",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            color: Color(0xFFF7CA18),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use this code:

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius))),
      ),
      child: Text("ok"),
    )
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code for a transparent rounded button by passing a transparent color to the color property inside `BoxDecoration`. 
eg. `color: Colors.transparent`.
Also, take note that this button makes use of only the `Container` and `GestureDetector` widgets.

```
Container(
    height: 50.0,
    child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Color(0xFFF05A22),
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    width: 1.0,
                ),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                        child: Text(
                           "BUTTON",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFF05A22),
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                letterSpacing: 1,
                            ),
                        ),
                    )
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

[image: Transaparent Background Button]

Answer (score 6):

If anybody is looking for complete circular button then I achieved it this way:

```
Center(
            child: SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: Size(80, 80), // Button width and height
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.pink[300], // Button color
                  child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.yellow, // splash color
                    onTap: () {}, // Button pressed
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.linked_camera), // Icon
                        Text("Picture"), // Text
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `ButtonTheme()`:

[image]

**Here is example code -**

```
ButtonTheme(
    minWidth: 200.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
    child: RaisedButton(
        elevation: 5.0,
        hoverColor: Colors.green,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Text(
            "Place Order",
            style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for your problem. You just have to take a simple container with a border radius in boxdecoration.

```
new Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
        color: Colors.blue,
    ),

    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: new Text(
                    "Next",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Button"),
          onPressed: (){},
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red))
        )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62607091/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

One of the simplest ways to create a rounded button is to use a `FlatButton` and then specify the roundness by setting its `shape` property. Follow the code below

```js
FlatButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
  color: Colors.black,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
  child: child: Text(
    "Button",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    print('Button pressed');
  },
),
```

> Note: In order to change the roundness adjust the value inside `BorderRadius.circular()`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to Use `MaterialButton` then,

You can add `RoundedRectangleBorder` Given in `Shape` Like this,

```
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
  height: 34,
  color: colorWhite,
  highlightColor: colorSplash,
  splashColor: colorSplash,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
    side: BorderSide(
      color: colorGrey,
      width: 0.6,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text("CANCEL"),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

After the Null safety, use ElevatedButton not RaisedButton because RaisedButton is depreciated as the docs says.

```
             child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Add item to the list'),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Common.buttonColor),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Now we have an *Icon* button to achieve a rounded button click and overlay. However, the background color is not yet available, but the same can be achieved by the Circle avatar widget as follows:

```
CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF4F3FA),
    child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () => FlushbarHelper.createInformation(
                             message: 'Work in progress...')
                             .show(context),
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```
Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: ButtonTheme(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
        child: RaisedButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                onPressed: () async {
                    // Do something
                },
                color: Colors.red[900],
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Button Text,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom view and put it inside a GestureDetector for it to behave like a button. The benefit is that you can provide endless types of custom decoration (including making it round with specified radius) to the container.

Answer (score 3):

### New Elevate Button

#### Style

```
customElevatedButton({radius, color}) => ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius == null ? 100 : radius),
    ),
    primary: color,
);
```

#### Icon

```
Widget saveIcon() => iconsStyle1(
    Icons.save,
);

// Common icon style

iconsStyle1(icon) => Icon(
    icon,
    color: white,
    size: 15,
);
```

#### Button use

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
    icon: saveIcon(),
    style:
        customElevatedButton(color: Colors.green[700]),
    label: Text('Save',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    onPressed: () {
    },
),
```

Answer (score 2):

> In Flutter, the `Container()` widget is used for styling your widget. Using the `Container()` widget, you can set a border or rounded corner of any widget.

If you want to set any type of styling and set the decoration, put that widget into the `Container()` widget. That provides many properties to the decoration.

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)), // Make rounded corner
  child: Text("Click"),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another cool solution that works in 2021:

```
TextButton(
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Text('Follow Us'.toUpperCase()),
    ),
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 2,
        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),)
    ),
    onPressed: () {
        print('Pressed');
    },
),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
addButton() {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 45,
        width: 200,
        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
          onPressed: () async {},
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  )),
            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(1),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add, size: 18),
          label: Text("Add question"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

you can use this style for your elevatedButton to make it circular

```
style: ButtonStyle(
              elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(8.0),
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Constants().orangeColor),
              textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<CircleBorder>(
                CircleBorder(),
              ),
              shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Constants().orangeColor),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

With Flutter version 2, try this

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side:
                    BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(5.0),),),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
        elevation:
            MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(8.0),
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15.0,
                vertical: 10.0),),),
    onPressed: (){},
    child: Text('Button'),)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a material button if you are using the Material App as your main Widget.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
  child: Material(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),//Set this up for rounding corners.
    shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
    child: MaterialButton(
      minWidth: 200.0,
      height: 42.0,
      onPressed: (){//Actions here//},
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      child: Text('Log in', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     Container(
        width: yourWidth,
        height: yourHeight ,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: radius,
            gradient: yourGradient,
            border: yourBorder),
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: {} (),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: radius),
    .......
```

and use the same radius.

Answer (score 1):

Container with round border color:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
  ),
  child: Text("Some Text"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a TextButton in a Container widget like the below code snippet:

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
  ),
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // To do
    },
    child: Text("Go to Change Language Screen "),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this-Just use FloatingActionButton for Proper Rounded Button.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Floating Action Button'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40.0,
  child: MaterialButton(
    child: Text("Button"),
    color: Colors.blue,
    disabledColor: Colors.blue,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0), // Change your border radius here
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

`ElevatedButton` is rounded by default in Material Design 3. Turn Material Design 3 on with this flag:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
  //...
),
```

This button

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text("Press me!"),
),
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Read more about this [here](https://www.christianfindlay.com/blog/flutter_material_design_3_rounded_buttons).

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      margin: margin,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor,
        gradient: gradient,
        border: Border.all(color: borderColor),
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        boxShadow: boxShadow,
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onPressed,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        child: Padding(
          padding: padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

it is a transparent button style that also shows the effect of the press.

Answer (score 0):

**Evaluated Button with custom text**

```
ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                "Submit",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                ),
                visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 2),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you also want to have an icon beside your text:

```
 Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextButton(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('Some Text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                  ],
                ),
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                  iconColor: Colors.blue,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MaterialButton with rounded radius like this.

```
MaterialButton(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))
            ),
            color: Colors.grey,
            onPressed: (){
          }, child: Text("Click Me"),)
```