# how to change border radius of elevated button flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created two buttons in a row using flutter. now I want to change border-radius o=f buttons. how can I do this properly? the picture shows the buttons I was created.

[image]

```
Widget lbsButton() => Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 80,
            height:50,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('lbs'),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(mainPurpleText),

              ),
              
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 80,
            height:50,
            child: new ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('kg' , style:TextStyle(color:Colors.grey,fontSize:13),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>( Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I should note that using style on the widget is somewhat like using style in html tags. Similarly to the html recommendation of using CSS classes instead of style, in flutter you should prefer to use Themes and custom Widgets instead of styling individual widgets.

Answer (score 9):

```dart
return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Text('test'),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            // Change your radius here
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thanks but when I add all these changes to my first button, as per the code my second button code became red. what should I do?  buttons are in same row one after the other

Answer (score 5):

The elevated button widget has a shape property which you can use as shown in the below snippet.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(mainPurpleText),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
          ),
      ),
      child: Text('Submit'),
      onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: how to add background color to same code

Comment: ok. just added   :)

Comment: thanks but when I add all those changes to my first button, as per the code my second button code became red. what should I do? i need both to be one after the other

Comment: what do you mean by code becomes red?

Comment: I mean the code after size box. it showing errors

Comment: just add `shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
          ),` to your `ButtonStyle`

Answer (score 3):

You can apply ElevatedButton.stylefrom() on the "style" property of ElevatedButton.

```
ElevatedButton(       
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
             ),
           ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('kg'),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ButtonStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html) and I think it is kind of similar  [Create a rounded button / button with border-radius in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49991444/10157127).

```dart
style: ButtonStyle(
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
      RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius:
        BorderRadius.circular(18.0), // radius you want
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.transparent, //color
    ),
  )),
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but when I add all this changes to my first button, as per the code , my second button code became red. what should I do? its on same row

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app,