# How can I upgrade a "RaisedButton" to "ElevatedButton" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, syntax, upgrade

I got the following code and want to make it work:

```
              RaisedButton(
                child:
                    Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
                onPressed: _submit,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
              ),
```

I tried to change it to some point as the following:

```
          ElevatedButton(
            child:
                Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
            onPressed: _submit,
            style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                )
              )
            ),

            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
          ),
```

But I don't know what to do with `padding`, `color`, and `textColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to convert the `RaisedButton` to an `ElevatedButton`.

On the `ElevatedButton` use:

- For the `textColor` use the `TextStyle` on the `Text` widget.
- For rounded corners, instead of `shape`, use the `style` property.
- For the `color`, use the `style` property.
- For `padding`, use the `style` property.

Your code should look like this:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        _authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button?.color),
      ),
      onPressed: _submit,
    )
```

##### See also:

- [Create a rounded button / button with border-radius in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991444/create-a-rounded-button-button-with-border-radius-in-flutter)
- [New Buttons and Button Themes - (Flutter.dev)](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP',
           style:TextStyle(color: 
              Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button?.color)),
          onPressed: _submit,
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
        )
```