# Inkwell for dummies

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

(...and with dummies I mean myself)

what am I doing wrong here?
I don't see any animation,
I tried to change the order of container/inkwell
because I saw somewhere that it creates some issue,
but I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

```
  class CardButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String input;
  CardButton({this.input});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[100],
      width: 50.0,
      height: 50.0,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Material(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.amber,
          onTap: draw(),
          child: Text(input),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

draw() {
  //todo
}
```

thanks in advance

[edit 25/10]

I tried out some of the solutions proposed,
but doing so the widget where this one is 'nested' throw me an error,

writing the widget where I use the "CardButton" below:

```
   class CardGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> cardList = [
    'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300.0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              CardButton(input: cardList[0]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[1]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[2])
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              CardButton(input: cardList[3]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[4]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[5])
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              CardButton(input: cardList[6]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[7]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[8])
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              CardButton(input: cardList[9]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[10]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[11]),
              CardButton(input: cardList[12])
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm adding here the screenshot of the app, the first is with my original code, 
the second (with the error) is with the "proposed" solution

[image: original code]
[image: modified code]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697978/6618622

Comment: CopsOnRoad - The linked answer solves a different problem.

Comment: can you please post a screenshot what you want

Comment: CopsOnRoad your code works <3 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the onTap function without the braces:

```
child: InkWell(
  splashColor: Colors.amber,
  onTap: draw, // don't use braces here (except your function returns
               // a reference to the actual onTap function.                      
  child: Text(input),
),
```

Note that with the current layout only the inner Text element is animated. If you want the InkWell to cover the entire button area you'll have to reorder the widget tree to:

Material > InkWell > Container > Text

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.grey[100],
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.amber,
        onTap: draw,
        child: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(input),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please mention what special thing you added in your answer which my answer failed to add?

Comment: [original post updated]
somehow using this code the widget "recipient" of this one throw me an error :/
didn't happen before, was a $hitty result, but not exploding.
adding the screenshot in the original post

Comment: CopsOnRoad - Sure, from what I understand from reading his code the poster alrady had everything right that is dealt with in your answer. What kept the inkwell from working is that he did not pass a reference to the draw function to the constructor but a function call instead. Your answer is not addressing this error.

Comment: sorry my comment was not very clear
- 1. changed 'Draw()' in 'draw', nothing changed;
- 2. changed my code with "Material > InkWell > Container > Text" posted by  Andreas, return me the error shown in the edited original post;
I posted the code where this widget is contained mostly to give a meaning to the screenshot, I don't think it contains any error (does it?)

Comment: I have checked your container code with my version of the button and it does not produce an error here. You can easily debug the error by looking up the code line that is given in the error message

Comment: Just run in debug mode. The code will halt at the exeption. Then climb up the call stack until you get to your own code that  produces the error.

Comment: CopsOnRoad - Thanks for letting me know that I could have made myself clearer. I have now edited my answer.