# How do I add an ink splash to a draggable widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to show the ink splash animation on drag start. I've already tried wrapping the draggable in an inkwell but the effect doesn't show.

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TES'),
        ),
        body: Draggable(
          child: Tile.draw(tileSize, val, 0.0, Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          feedback:
              Tile.draw(tileSize, val, 20.0, Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          childWhenDragging: InkWell(
            onTap: () => print('INK!'),
            highlightColor: Colors.green,
            splashColor: Colors.green,
            customBorder: PolygonBorder(sides: 6, borderRadius: 6),
            child:
                Tile.draw(tileSize, val, 0.0, Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
          ),
        ));
```

Comment: Probably a variation of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect/45426828#45426828

Comment: I changed the material type to transparency and there is still no ink animation. I think the problem is that the InkWell's gesture handler is being overridden by the Draggable one. I tested this by giving InkWell an onTap that prints to the console and nothing prints. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you add a method a dummy method to onTap?

Can you post a sample code?

Comment: Draggable(
        child: Tile.draw(tileSize, val, 0.0, Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        feedback:
            Tile.draw(tileSize, val, 20.0, Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        childWhenDragging: InkWell( 
          onTap: () => print('INK!'),
          highlightColor: Colors.green,
          splashColor: Colors.green,
          customBorder: PolygonBorder(sides: 6, borderRadius: 6),
          child: Tile.draw(tileSize, val, 0.0, Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
        ),
      ));

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Can you edit your main question and add it there?