# Flutter InkWell with Container as child is not showing effects

Tags: flutter, dart, button, widget, containers

I have a simple `InkWell` with a `Container` inside of it. I would like to have the `ripple` affect but it is not showing. Neither is `hoverColor`/`focusColor`...

My button:

```
class EntryNextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print("Container clicked");
      },
      child: Container(
        ...
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect

Answer (score 1):

The `InkWell` widget must have a `Material` widget as an ancestor.

Wrap your InkWell in Material widget.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a **`Scaffold`** or at least a **`Material`** as ancestor