# How to change background color of Flutter DataTable on hover over rows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-datatable

I have a DataTable in my scene. I want to change the background color of rows when the user hovers over any row. I found several samples on flutter.dev but none are working.

For instance, look at the following code ([full code](https://flutlab.io/ide/d84072b6-f200-4209-a15b-2847cded09eb)). Although I have green as the background color, it doesn't turn into blue when I hover over the rows.

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(_getDataRowColor),
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Role',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
          onSelectChanged: (isSelected) => {
            print('Item 1 clicked!')
          },
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
          onSelectChanged: (isSelected) => {
            print('Item 2 clicked!')
          },
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
          onSelectChanged: (isSelected) => {
            print('Item 3 clicked!')
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Color _getDataRowColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
    };

    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
    return Colors.green;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found where is the problem. The following code fixes the hover over the row issue that I asked in the question. However, having a transparent background for all of the rows by default is the expense of my solution.

```
Color _getDataRowColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
    };

    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
    //return Colors.green; // Use the default value.
    return Colors.transparent;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest to return `null` instead of `Colors.transparent`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing also harmed me, I fixed with the same solution to this problem.
[InkWell not showing ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for changing background color on hover over rows

```
DataTable(
                showCheckboxColumn: false,
                columns: const [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('First column')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Second column')),
                ],
                rows: List.generate(5, (index) {
                  return DataRow(
                      onSelectChanged: (selected) {},
                      color: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                          return Colors.grey.shade400;
                        }
                        return null;
                      }),
                      cells: const [
                        DataCell(Text('first cell')),
                        DataCell(Text('second cell')),
                      ]);
                }),
     );
```

Important part is: add **onSelectChanged** property in DataRow

```
onSelectChanged: (selected) {}
```

and then add **color** property in DataRow

```
color: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
       if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
           return Colors.grey.shade400;
       }
       return null;
    }),
```

If you do not want to show checkbox column then add **showCheckboxColumn: false** in DataTable