# Inkwell in flutter not showing the correct color

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the `Inkwell` widget to show ripple effect but I am not able to get it to the color I want.

Partial Code:

```
Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  splashColor: Colors.black87,
                  highlightColor: Colors.black87,
                  focusColor: Colors.black87,
                  hoverColor: Colors.black87,
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
```

Here I have shown the important parts of the code. I am only getting white ripple even though I set it to black.

What is the issue here?

Please comment if you need more information.

Comment: you can wrap Theme with ListTile or Inkwell - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71675500/9372923

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your widget with the Theme and give the color

**Output :-**

[image]

**Code :-**

```
Theme(
            data: ThemeData(splashColor: Colors.black87),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              splashColor: Colors.black87,
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                title: Text("TEXT"),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: data: ThemeData(cardColor: Colors.white),

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use Ink widget wrapped in an InkWell.

```
InkWell(
 onTap: () {}, // Handle your onTap 
 child: Ink(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  color: Colors.blue,
 ),
)
```

Note: All credit goes to this post answer:[InkWell not showing ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect)