# Flutter: Inkwell ripple effect hid behind a color filled container child

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material3

I am working on a combination of Icon + Text button using **Material 3** as my theme. I have done my homework and researched as much as I could possibly do, as a last desperate attempt, I am posting this question. I am beginner with Flutter.

[image: Image of said custom widget]

ANd this is what happens upon clicking:

[image: GIF of clicking on the widget]

Here is the relevant code of the widget:

```dart
class TransactionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const TransactionButton({Key? key, required this.icon, required this.text, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  final void Function() onTap;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(icon, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,),
            const SizedBox(width: 8,),
            Text(
              text,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Remember, **Material 3 is enabled**. If you carefuly examine the attached gif you will find that at the corners I can see the ripple effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yeah, great, I saw that earilear but couldn't figure out that I was supposed to remove color from container itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding this to InkWell

```
 splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I did want a splash but above the container

Comment: In that case, adding ElevatedButton with the cosmetics you applied in the Container widget could help. You will have the splash over the Button.